# Doubt about strictfp and StrictMath

Tags: java, math, floating-point, strictfp

I have a little technical question, is it the same to call:

```
   public static strictfp double myMethod(double phi){
       return Math.exp(phi);
   }
```

or:

```
   public static double myMethod(double phi){
       return StrictMath.exp(phi);
   }
```

Or does the `strictfp` keyword just applies to the basic arithmetic operations `+ - * /` used inside the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or does the strictfp keyword just applies to the basic arithmetic operations + - * / used inside the method?

The `strictfp` keyword only applies to operations in the method or class it modifies.  It doesn't reroute calls to `Math` functions to `StrictMath`, so you need to explicitly use `StrictMath` instead of `Math`.

From http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2se/jdk1.2/javamath/strictfp.html

> If a **floating point expression** is within a `strictfp` **"scope"**, the results will be as predictable as described in IEEE 754 ...